# Why aren't my Guidewire rating overrides being applied/copied to reinstatement transactions?

Tags: rating, guidewire

GuidewireRating Override on a Reinstatement Transaction doesn't work as expected.

We are Trying to expand our current LOB to utilize Rating Overrides. However we are facing an issue when Rating was overridden in New Business manually and then did a cancellation, the overrides are carried on to cancellation but when a Reinstatement happens on cancellation, the overrides are not getting copied over.

Has anyone ever faced this kind of issue and if so what would you have done to resolve this issue.TIA.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised to hear you've lost overrides on a reinstatement as this is not the default behavior. To prove this, I attempted to replicate your issue using an LOB I had at hand, which was the latest version of our Commercial Property Standards-Based Template line (CP7). Specifically, I did the following:

1. Create a submission and quote it
2. Create overrides on the quote
3. Bind the submission with my overrides
4. Cancel the policy (full term)
5. Reinstate the policy

When I followed these steps, I saw that my overrides created in step 2 did indeed carry over to the reinstatement, which was the behavior I expected, and the opposite of what you're reporting. This leads me to suspect that some customization you've made to your ReinstatementProcess or the PolicyPeriodPlugin impl class might be your root cause here.

I'd recommend you try this:

1. Add the following block of code to PolicyPeriodPlugin.gs (or whatever your custom impl of PolicyPeriodPlugin.gwp is), at the beginning of the method postCreateDraftBranchInSamePeriod().

```
print("All costs just after creation!!!")
    period.AllCosts.each(\elt -> {
      print(elt.TypeIDString + " " + elt.OverrideAmount + " " + elt.ActualAmount + " " + elt.CoverableName)
    })
```

This method is the first hook you have after the product code calls createDraftBranchInSamePeriod(). If you see the cost echoed with the overridden amount, then you've got some customization which is removing it which runs after this line. Add the code again to the end of this method, and this will help you sort out of if some of the post-processing in that method is at fault.

2. Add the same code to the ReinstatementProcessImpl.gs class's constructor (this is the ootb implementation, you may have this customized, this would be specified in your JobProcessCreationPlugin). There's other lifecycle methods in this class which you could use the same method on to help identify where your cost overrides are getting removed. Ultimately what you're looking for is the first time your costs are echoed out without the override.  That'll help you sort out what piece of code is deleting them.

Please do report back on your findings, especially if there's some more I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

I could see that solution is for flat cancellation, could you try the mid term cancellation and then reinstate then override does nor carry forward it creates new slice